# WPF: Button not taking the full space in a Listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, styles

I've a `ListBox`, in which I will have some `Button` added by prism.

For now, I've the following code(with some dummy button here just for testing purpose:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Black" DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">

            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <Button>Button 1</Button>
        <Button >Button 2</Button>
    </ListBox>
    <ContentControl></ContentControl>
</DockPanel>
```

The issue that I'm having currently is that my buttons are not taking the full space:

[image]

- How to make sure it use all the available space?
- Is there some way to ensure that all buttons will be have the height = to the width?

(just to be clear, I don't want anything set on the button since they will be provided by Prism from different modules)

When I run the application and focus an object, it seems we see that the `ListBoxItem`is taking the full place but the Button inside isn't:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to make sure it use all the available space?

This is due to how the `ListBox` control's template is designed.  To remove the small margin at the left and right of the button, set Padding=0 for the ListBoxItem style.

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

[image: No padding]

> Is there some way to ensure that all buttons will be have the height = to the width?

You could do a `RelativeSource` binding to bind the container's height to the actual width of the parent `ListBox`:

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox},Path=ActualWidth}" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

[image: Square buttons]

Comment: I just tried, but it doesn't seems to change anything. I added a screenshot with how it react at the runtime.

Comment: @J4N what is that last `ContentControl` doing there?  Remove that also and the buttons will stretch to fill the DockPanel.

Comment: The `ListBox` will be a menu, the `ContentControl` is just a place holder for now. I want the button take all the width within the listbox, the listbox will not use the whole space. In your screenshot, we also see that the button is not using the whole place(check, there is a gap on the right/left).

Comment: @J4N ok, I think I understand now -- see my edit.  The key is still the ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: @J4N if you are trying to present buttons, you might consider using `ItemsControl` instead of `ListBox`.  The latter supports selection, the former just presents its children, with no extra styling.

Comment: Okay, but I will have selection at the end(current menu will be highlighted)

Comment: Also, any idea how to "bind" the height of each button to its width with the style?

Comment: @J4N You can move the height setter into the ItemContainerStyle -- updated above.

Comment: Thank you four sharing your knowledge :)